# IN operator does not work in MongoDB IQueryable

Tags: c#

I want to use `In` operator in below statement instead of ==. My filteredList is MongoDB IQueryable. When I use IN operator then get error "IN does not support".

```
filteredList = filteredList
  .Where(item => item.ID=="1" );
```

Comment: Can you show how you're using `In`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by augmenting the LINQ with the standard typed Builders.

```cs
var inFilter = Builders<Item>.Filter.In(x => x.ID, new[] { "value1", "value2" });

filteredList = filteredList.Where(_ => inFilter.Inject());
```

https://kevsoft.net/2020/08/18/augmenting-mongodb-linq-with-low-level-mongo-query.html#augmenting-linq

Comment: Showing exception : The LinqExtensions.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses.

Comment: @RajeshBargode are you not using it in a where statement?